# What is the meaning of the belly button?

Tags: character, the-nines

In the beginning of the film [*The Nines*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0810988/) Ryan Reynolds' character gets out of the shower and freaks out because he does not have a belly button. This, of course, is later explained being that he's not actually human, but a God like entity that has created the entire world around him... However, there are several shots in the film where we can see he clearly has a belly button... Was this just something that was overlooked in production? Or, was it due to the crack he and the hooker had obtained earlier in the film? I know the movie has many different interpretations of various events throughout, I was just curious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most obvious explanation (e.g. as to why he has a belly button in later scenes) is that it was indeed overlooked in production.

Ryan Reynolds states in this interview that his lack of belly button was an integral part of the plotline so it's very unlikely that they would have deliberately subverted it without some kind of [callback](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/CallBack).

> **Interviewer :** *“The Nines” once again features you shirtless. Is that in your contract?*
>
> **Reynolds :** *No! I try to avoid it, actually. This will be the only movie out of the last four that I had to do it. But it was necessary
>   for the narrative, because you had to see his belly button — or lack
>   thereof. That’s key.*